# how to update set with group by sql

Tags: mysql

I have `absen` table with columns like,

[image: Absen's table]

And I query it like,

```
SELECT count( tgl ) AS total, absen.id, absen.status, absen.kondisi,
CASE WHEN (weekday( tgl ) <=3) THEN date( tgl + INTERVAL( 3 - weekday( tgl ) ) DAY ) 
ELSE date( tgl + INTERVAL( 3 +7 - weekday( tgl ) ) DAY )
END AS tglitung
FROM absen
WHERE absen.status = 'm'
GROUP BY absen.id, tglitung
```

It results as

[image]

I want to update `SET kondisi='yes'`, when `GROUP BY absen.id='15' AND tglitung='2016-01-14'`

How to use set update with case like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE absen SET kondisi = 'yes'
WHERE id = 15 
    AND (CASE WHEN (WEEKDAY( tgl ) <=3) THEN DATE( tgl + INTERVAL( 3 - WEEKDAY( tgl ) ) DAY ) 
    ELSE DATE( tgl + INTERVAL( 3 +7 - WEEKDAY( tgl ) ) DAY )
    END) = '2016-01-14';
```